# Basic Python Functions For Analyzing Loan Pools?

Tags: python, pandas, math, finance

How can I use Python to predict the value of a loan pool and create a loan loss curve? What other useful functions exist within the capabilities of Python that are useful for valuing and analyzing large loan pools?

Assumptions: the data is in Excel and there are over 1 million data points (possibly even a few million).

Additionally, which metrics are best to go off of when valuing a loan pool that is filled with borrowers who are of various levels of creditworthiness, at different points in their loans, all of which have differing lengths, etc.

Any sources of learning for this material would be much appreciated.
Thanks so much.

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question. Furthermore, the request for external sources is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Amazon has several books about finance with Python such as "Python for Finance: Mastering Data-Driven Finance" which, being an O'Reilly book, is probably good. Nothing short of a book can really answer your questions.

Comment: Asking how I can use Python to predict the value of a loan pool is too broad? How would you suggest I narrow this down John Coleman?

Comment: [Predicative analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_analytics) is a very broad field. Your first sentence is implicitly two questions, neither of which have a single answer since there are a variety of approaches. Your second sentence is another question. Your third sentence is a in effect a fourth broad question about interacting with pandas and Excel with large datasets. Your fourth sentence (third paragraph) is another huge sweeping question, and your final sentence is still another question. Seems fairly broad to me.

Comment: From the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."